# Is it possible to guess n-th term of given number sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematica

Consider if we have number sequence e.g. $\left\{ 1, 6, 62, 344, ... \right\}$
I'd like to ask if is it possible to compute or estimate form of $n$-th element of this series.

Is it possible with Mathematica or maybe some math processes? I'll be glad for all hints and solution to this topic. 
Greetings,

Comment: WolframAlpha can often guess, but it doesn't know anything about this. OEIS doesn't find it either

Comment: Where does the sequence come from? Any hint on how it is generated? With that, it _might_ be possible to come up with a formula...

Comment: @vonbrand This example is "random". I need to design simulator that will count something and the output might be looking like this. I think we can consider that for all $n$ : $a_{n+1} > a_{n} $ and increasing speed will be faster than linear.

Comment: @Cocopuffs: I don't think WolframAlpha can generate series for $[\sqrt{n}]^2+n$?

Comment: @Inceptio It looks for "holonomic sequences", which has something to do with the generating power series satisfying a simple (polynomials) differential equation. It doesn't do everything, but it often helps.

Comment: *Mathematica* has `FindSequenceFunction[]` for the purpose of guessing.

Comment: @Cocopuffs: Well, yes. But this might be a series which uses  something non-trivial ones?

Comment: Use Lagrange interpolation on the first $n$ terms to give some degree-$n-1$ polynomial and hope the $n+1$th term makes sense that way?

Comment: @HSN : If you don't know the distribution of the data from which your sample is taken from (the whole sequence), using an interpolation polynomial of about the same size as the number of samples is quite likely to "overfit" the sample. Which means you will have zero error on your sample, but generalization will be very bad. (Unless your sequence comes from this exact polynomial or a similar one of course)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how your sequence is generated.

If it comes from a real world problem, the ideal "function" which perfectly models your data is usually too complicated and takes too many parameters into account to even think about inferring it.

However there are a lot of statistical tools at your disposal to try and fit the data to predict further values. The problem you're facing is called "Regression" which is basically trying to find a simpler version of the "ideal function" which will model your data as much as it cans while still optimizing the prediction of future values.